# Color Changer for multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I have an existing color changer for a page, currently it will change the "background-color, color, and a:link" colors. im trying to add another field to change for the a:hover but I cannot get it to work for some reason. I have even tried the "itemlist:hover" since that seems to be what is setting the default for it at the moment.

I have tried using the same css tag as what is setting the default, I have also tried "a:hover", and "itemlist a:hover" I do not know enough about scripts to get this to work on my own..

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Original') {
    $("body").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $("body").css('color', '#000000');
    $("a:link").css('color', '#0077EE');
    $("a:hover").css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
    $("a:hover").css('color', '#000000');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('color', '#000000');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Desktop') {
    $("body").css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
    $("body").css('color', '#000000');
    $("a:link").css('color', '#0000EE');
    $("a:hover").css('background-color', '#2A2B2A');
    $("a:hover").css('color', '#000000');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('background-color', '#2A2B2A');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('color', '#000000');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Grey') {
    $("body").css('background-color', '#5B5E5B');
    $("body").css('color', '#C6DDF0');
    $("a:link").css('color', '#8CC06E');
    $("a:hover").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $("a:hover").css('color', '#FFFFFF');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('color', '#FFFFFF');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'DarkGrey') {
    $("body").css('background-color', '#2A2B2A');
    $("body").css('color', '#C6DDF0');
    $("a:link").css('color', '#8CC06E');
    $("a:hover").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $("a:hover").css('color', '#FFFFFF');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('color', '#FFFFFF');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Terminal') {
    $("body").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $("body").css('color', '#7FFF00');
    $("a:link").css('color', '#7EC0EE');
    $("a:hover").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $("a:hover").css('color', '#000000');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $(".listitem:hover").css('color', '#000000');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}

a:link {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.links {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.listitem {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.listitem a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.listitem a:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  width: 100%;
}

.listitem:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.form-group>label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <!-- Link_1 -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="http://google.com/" id="input-lnk_link1" target="_blank">
      <li class="listitem">
        Link One</li>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- Link_2 -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="http://yahoo.com/" id="input-lnk_link2" target="_blank">
      <li class="listitem">
        Link Two</li>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="styles">
  <div class="stylechanger">
    <hr style="margin-left:0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select class="form-control input-sm height25" style="color:#000000; margin-left: -10px;" id="select">
        <option style="background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000" value="Original">Choose a Style (Default)
        </option>
        <option style="background-color:#D3D3D3; color:#000000" value="Desktop">Desktop
        </option>
        <option style="background-color:#5B5E5B; color:#C6DDF0" value="Grey">Grey
        </option>
        <option style="background-color:#2A2B2A; color:#C6DDF0" value="DarkGrey">Dark Grey
        </option>
        <option style="background-color:#000000; color:#7FD700" value="Terminal">Terminal
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected results:
Im wanting it to change the background, text, link, hover link, and hover background colors upon selecting the style from the drop down menu.

Actual results:
currently, I can only get it to change the background, text, and link colors when selecting the style from the drop down menu.

Comment: ":hover" is only going to find elements that are actually currently hovered.  Given that you are clicking a select box, only it is currently hovered.

Comment: so if I am understanding correctly, the way the color changer that I have functions is it adds a style="" with the replacement info, would this be the reason im having issues with doing the hover since hover is something done in the css not in the lines style?

Comment: `$('a:hover')` is not selecting css rules.  It is selecting elements.  Specifically, it is saying, find all the `a` tags in the DOM that are currently hovered.  Which if you are currently hovering a `<select>`, then **no** `a` tags are hovered.  You cannot set conditional css rules like `:hover` inline on elements.  You have to define those in css rules.

Comment: thank you, I ended up removing the :hover from the styles changer and set it in the css with a unique background color and text color.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(".listitem").on('hover', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
});
```

Comment: tried this ive a few different ways as well as in the exact way you have it and was not able to get it to function